# Methods to re-direct a static page

Tags: html

certain time I'm getting 404 error when the static content is getting pushed from CDN. Is it possible for me to re-direct this page automatically to another page.

Answer (score 0):

To do this I need to edit “.htaccess” which located at the root folder of the particular website. If you are unable to see the file, make sure you allow to view hidden files since “.htaccess” is a hidden file. If it still not there, then create it.